# Pictures from iPhone to clients FTP server - Directly (iPhone->FTP) or Cloud (iPhone->Amazon->FTP)

Tags: ios, objective-c

My clients wants to take pictures with their iPhone's and place them collectible on their server, suggested by FTP.

I can see there is two solutions:

1. Directly upload from the iPhone to the FTP server. My colleague can make so the get the ActiveDirectery username and password, so they do not use the same password all of them.
2. Upload them directly to Amazon S3, where I then have a worker which takes the image and puts it on the ftp server. I can do this easily with Python. I will use Kinvey to manage users.

Is nr. 2 overkill on short terms? Or is the downsides with creating a FTP connection on a iPhone?

My boss thinks it makes it unnecessary more complicated with that extra link. I can easily see what my boss mean, and think he is right. The problem is that I have not tried FTP'ing in Obj-C and do not know how hard or difficult it can might be. I know phonegap, which could easily upload to Amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know phonegap and python, no. 2 is not an overkill.

Working with [FTP in Objective C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html) is not that difficult, but username and password could be captured if they sent in plain-text.